# Send UDP messages over the internet with an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, network-programming, udp

I am trying to figure out how to send UDP messages to and from an iPhone to a computer over the internet.

I can send messages fine within the local network but I dont really know where to start with getting outside the local network.

Also if you could supply some links to a tutorial or example that would be amazing.

Comment: How do you sent within the local net? Simply replace the destination address with an "outside" address.

Comment: there are firewalls in the way to prevent that and I dont have access to do port forwarding on one side.

Comment: Look for `httptunnel` (available as open source), and in that package the client code.

Comment: I have multiple mobile devices which would include iphone android and blackberry all getting different udp messages. httptunnel only works on one port and would need multiple for every device.